# Decoding LoRaWAN packets (Join-Accept)

Tags: node.js, parsing, unmarshalling, lorawan

I am trying to understand how the join-accept message is handled on the microcontroller side. In the image below the captured packet from the network server to the LoRaWAn sensor. The incoming message data contains 44 bytes. however, PHYPayload contains 33 bytes when running .js code which decodes the payload

[image: WireShark capture of Join-accept]

however, PHYPayload contains 33 bytes when running .js code which decodes the payload. So my question is **what are the rest 11 bytes responsible for and how the parse function works, for the LoRaWAN Join-Accept message ?**

Important: when I try to reduce the number of bytes from 44, to parse, the decoding result is a mess.

Does this expression is true: **Message_to_decode = Payload (33 bytes) - MHDR (1 byte) ?**

[image: running .js decoder code]

The js code of decoder.

[image: .js decoder code]

Comment: Web version of lora-packet can be found here: https://lorawan-packet-decoder-0ta6puiniaut.runkit.sh/

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification [LoRaWAN 1.0.4](https://lora-alliance.org/resource_hub/lorawan-104-specification-package/) a join accept is built up of

- MHDR  (single-octet MAC header) => 1 byte (`0b00100000` = `0x20`for join accept, LoRaWAN Major version = Revesion 1)
- Join-Accept (3 octet JoinNonce, 3 octet NedId, 4 octet DevAddr, 1 octet DLSettings, 1 octet RxDelay, 16 octets CFList (optional)) => 12 or 28 bytes but it is encrypted with the AppKey (AES128) resulting in 16 or 32 bytes
- MIC (4-octet message integrity code) => 4 bytes

I'm not sure how your lengths are calculated but I think the answer to your question, where are the extra bytes coming from, is from the padding required for the encryption.